# Compact and convergent countable filter base

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that if a metric space $(S,d)$ is compact, then every countable filter base is included in a convergent one.

My efforts:

I suppose the "one" in the problem is also countable. Otherwise I can let it be a base for an ultrafilter and directly use the theorem about converging ultrafilters and compactness.

Given a countable basis {$B_n$}, we can pick a point $x_n$ from the element $B_n$. Since $(S,d)$ is a compact metric space, every sequence has a convergent subsequence. Thus {$x_n$} has a convergent subsequence, say, converging to $x$. We can add open balls $B(x, 1/n)$ to {$B_n$}. The new collection is still countable. But it may not be a filter base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you interpret *convergent one* as *convergent **countable** filter base*, you can use the easy solution with a small modification. First extend the countable filter base $\mathscr{B}$ to an ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$, and let $p$ be the point to which $\mathscr{U}$ converges. Then $B\left(p,\frac1n\right)\in\mathscr{U}$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so just extend $\mathscr{B}$ to $\mathscr{B}\cup\left\{B\left(p,\frac1n\right):n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$.

Comment: Like the attempt in the question, this extension might not be a filter base, but that's easy to fix --- just close it under finite intersection (or just pairwise intersection).